# Improper Integral $\int_{1/e}^1 \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{\ln{(x)}}} $

Tags: improper-integrals

I need some advice on how to evaluate it.
$$\int\limits_\frac{1}{e}^1 \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{\ln{(x)}}} $$
Thanks!

Comment: The integral is not well-defined. $\ln(1/e)=-1$ ...

Comment: Try a u-substitution with $u=\ln(x)$.

Comment: so I need to change $\int\limits_\frac{1}{e}^1$ to?

Comment: @AndyBromberg if I`m doing it so I get $$\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}$$ but still I need to change the values of the integral right?

Comment: Yep! So you'll get:
$$\int_{-1}^{0} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}$$

Comment: @OfirAttia: your solution should look like $2 \sqrt{\log x}\,\Big|_{\frac{1}{e}}^{1}$

Comment: @Alex but ln of $\frac{1}{e}$ is negative and then its not defined there

Comment: @OfirAttia, yes, with these bounds you're going to get an imaginary answer.

Comment: @OfirAttia: are you familiar with complex numbers?

Comment: @DonAntonio: perhaps you mean $$\int_{1/e}^1\frac1{x\sqrt{|\log(x)|}}\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: Indeed @robjohn, thanks.

Comment: @Alex familiar yes but, I just need to say if its improper or not.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399384/improper-integral-int-03-fracdxx-12-3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a hint:
$$
\int_{1/e}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{\ln x}} {\huge(}\frac{dx}{x}{\huge)}.
$$
What that is hinting at is what you need to learn in order to understand substitutions.  It's all about the chain rule.  The part in the gigantic parentheses becomes $du$.

Comment: I understand, but still my problem is the know when to change the limits, I get : $$\int^1_\frac{1}{e} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}$$

Comment: You have $t = \ln x$.  When $x = 1/e$, then $t=\ln(1/e)=-1$.  When $x=1$, then $t=\ln 1 = 0$.  So you have $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^0 \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}$.  Since you're talking about square roots of negative numbers, you have a question of how to make sense of those.  One branch, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

To recap all that happened in the comments section:

Based on the initial problem of$$\int\limits_\frac{1}{e}^1 \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{\ln{(x)}}}$$

We perform a u-substitution with $u=\ln{x}$ and $du=\frac{dx}{x}$. Also, the bounds are converted to $\ln\frac{1}{e}=-1$ and $\ln{1}=0$. So we have:

$$\int\limits_{-1}^{0} \frac{du}{\sqrt{u}}=2\sqrt{u}\big|_{-1}^{0}=0-2i=-2i$$

And that's the solution!